# Find specific text in files

Tags: windows, shell, command-line, windows-8

Simple as the title says... I thought I could use these commands because of what the `find` command says on its help but it is not working for me. Am I missing anything?

```
dir /s /f *.txt | find "READONLY"
```

With that I want to find every occurrence of the word "READONLY" in every `.txt` file.

**Edit:** While writing this question I looked for the suggestions and the `findstr` command showed up. But it is not finding anything at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure what you are trying to do.

The /F option is not valid for the DIR command. ***Correction*** *- I'm told the /F option is a Windows 8 feature.* Ignoring that problem, your command is attempting to look for the string READONLY in the output of the DIR command. That will never happen unless a folder or file name contains the text "READONLY" in the name.

If you want to list files that contain "READONLY" in the file content, then:

```
findstr /s /m READONLY *.txt
```

The above is case sensitive. If you want case insensitive, then add the `/I` option.

```
findstr /s /m /i READONLY *.txt
```

If you want to list files that have the READONLY attribute, (you cannot modify them), then

```
dir /s /ar *.txt
```

Comment: /f (Full Path) is a valid flag for `dir` in Windows 8

Comment: you're right! I was using the pipe worng. This one did the trick thanks `findstr /s /m /i READONLY *.txt`

Comment: I'm voting this one as the answer since looks a lot simpler

Comment: @sebastian - Thanks for the info on the /F option. Live and learn :-)

Answer (score 1):

> find every occurrence of the word "READONLY" in every .txt file [recursively starting from the current directory]

```
for /f "tokens=1 delims=" %f in ('dir/s/b *.txt') do findstr "READONLY" %f
```

Be sure to replace % with %% if you're running within a script.

Comment: I thought it had to be a lot easier than using a for since the `find` says you can pipe files from other commands. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Try using

```
grep -R 'READONLY' *.txt
```